# error in posting weatherbit data + weatherbit parameters + Pixabay

Tags: javascript, html

1- when I run

```
npm run build-prod
npm run build-dev
npm start
```

and then enter any city, the below data appear but weatherbit data appeared as undefined but in VS they appeared , don't know what is the problem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CP6xk.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMhXa.png)

2- I used lat and lng data but when i try to fetch them from geoNames the below errors appear

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKq1p.png)

3- when i fetch image from pixabay API it doesn't appear and the below data appeare

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQtzE.png)

// link for my code
[enter link description here](https://github.com/BasmaElsisy1/Finallll.git)

Comment: Hi @basma. Welcome to SO!! Please add the exact error message you get in your question. I think it will be helpful. Cheers

Comment: I did, can you please help me

Comment: Hi @basma. Great! My comment was only intended to improve your question so that SO users have the maximum information to make the best answer. For my part, unfortunately, I don't have enough skills  in `javascript` to help you. Cheers